# Killing TCP Client Threads of TCP Server in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcpserver

i have a TCP server software. I open a thread for every TCP client. (This is not important why i open a thread for every TCP client.) I want to kick a TCP client any time and want to kill its thread. How can i find the thread of TCP client that i want to kick out of server?

Thank you.

Comment: What information do you have that determines which thread should die?

Comment: Every thread works with client IP so i got the clients IP addresses.

Comment: " I open a thread for every TCP client. " - that is usually a really, really big mistake... just saying. My last TCP server is currently handling 50k+ concurrent connections - thread per client *really* doesn't scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep track of all TcpClient's in existence. For example, use a list to store them. That way you have access to them.